# exoplayer does not play 3k videos.It gives decoder failed exception

Tags: video, resolution, exoplayer2.x

If i initialise exoplayer without rendersfactory then high resolution videos gives decoders failed exception.
If i use default renders factory, videos are rotating sometime ,sometime not.

```
exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(holder.mVideoView.getContext()).setLoadControl(loadControl).build();

holder.mVideoView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
holder.mVideoView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
holder.mVideoView.setShutterBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
holder.mVideoView.setKeepContentOnPlayerReset(true);
exoPlayer.seekTo(0);
exoPlayer.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);

 mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
        new CacheDataSource.Factory()
                .setCache(SimpleMediaPlayer.getInstance(mContext))
                .setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
                        .setUserAgent(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name)))
                .setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR)
).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(videoItem.videoURL));

exoPlayer.addMediaSource(mediaSource);

exoPlayer.prepare();

exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
exoPlayer.play();
```

I am releasing player in onviewdettached and initialising player in onViewAttached in recyclerview by calling holder.player.stop and then release correctly.

please help.

high resolution videos should play without exception.

Comment: Add a full code snippet to check what you have tried so far.

Comment: added please check.With that code some videos fetching decoder error.but if i use renders factory then it plays but some videos rotate.

Comment: any updates on this issue? Facing the same :/